# ClassCastException - Customer and Customerservice are in unnamed module of loader app?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am trying to call my Customer Bean in my main app to test that my bean set up is correct (I can see them being created), and am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   com.r00107892.bank.domain.Customer cannot be cast to class
>   com.r00107892.bank.services.CustomerService
>   (com.r00107892.bank.domain.Customer and
>   com.r00107892.bank.services.CustomerService are in unnamed module of
>   loader 'app')     at com.r00107892.bank.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:24)

I have checked my Customer.java, CustomerDAO.java, CustomerDAOImpl.java, CustomerService.java, CustomerServiceImpl.java, my mainApp and my BeanConfig.java and I can't find an issue.

I changed my BeanConfig so that it no longer explicitly named Customer as a Bean and uses ComponentScan.

MainApp

```
@Configuration
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  context= new 
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext (BeanConfig.class);

        System.out.println("Bean names: " + Arrays.toString(context.getBeanNamesForType(BeanConfig.class)));

        CustomerService customerService = (CustomerService) context.getBean("customer");

System.out.println(customerService.getCustomerByAccountNumber('1'));

        context.close();
    }
    }
```

Customer.java

```
@Component
public class Customer{
public String name;
public int account;


public Customer() {

}

public Customer(int account, String name){

}

public String getName() {
    return name;

}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name=name;
}

public int getAccount() {
    return account;
}

public void setAccount(int account) {
    this.account = account;
}

public void myDetails() {
    System.out.println("My name is "+ this.name);
    System.out.println("My name is" + this.account);
    }

public String toString(String name, int account) {
    String sentence = name + " " + account;
    return sentence;

}
```

CustomerService

```
@Service
public interface CustomerService {

    Customer getCustomerByAccountNumber(int accountNumber);

}
```

CustomerServiceImpl

```
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    CustomerDAO customerDao;


    public Customer getCustomerByAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
        return customerDao.findById(accountNumber);
   }
```

I expect to see Customer name for account no 1 (already in database) to be printed out.

Comment: you have to annotate `CustomerServiceImpl` with `@Service` not interface `CustomerService`

Comment: When I do this, it still says NoSuchBeanDefinition. If I annotate the serviceImpl as a service, when I call my Bean do I still call CustomerService customerService = (CustomerService) context.getBean("customerService"); or is getBean "customer"

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
CustomerService customerService = (CustomerService) context.getBean("customerService");
```

You did not assign a name to the beans, so by default it will take the class name.
The bean is the customerService and not the customer (I assume you meant this to be an entity?)

Comment: Yes, I meant to make customer an entity. When I change to CustomerService as the bean, it says NoSuchBeanDefinition.

Comment: I did originally have a bean named customer defined in BeanConfig but that also gave the cast error.

Comment: where is your configuration? do you have `@ComponentScan` there?

Comment: My config is in BeanConfig.class, and has: Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.r00107892.bank")
public class BeanConfig {  - This is in the same package as my MainApp which is com.r00107892.bank